# How to have a route that goes to 2 destinations

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, routes

I need the ability to have routes like the following URLs.

```
/authorid
/documentid
/authorid/documentid
```

I am trying to not to do

```
/author/1   
/document/5
author/1/document/25
```

How can this be done?

Clarifications.
A document and an author can have the same id. BUT the author should take precedence.

Author: {ID: "djQuery" }

Document: { Aurhor: "Bob", ID: "djQuery" }

Should be accessible via /Bob/djQuery

But if you just go to /djQuery you should get a list of djQuery's documents.

Comment: Can you guarantee that a document will never have the same id as an author?

Comment: Do you mean where the `id` in `document(id)` is an integer? You you show how to URLs are meant to map to controller and actions?

Comment: @joshb: No not realy but author should take precedence. I.E   author djquery and document djquery should only be reachable via /djquery/djquery/

Comment: I think you are asking for trouble. Even if you manage to pull it off, you will end up with confusing URL structure. Secondly, although constrains can help you customize your routes I don't think having database access as part of your routes constrains (as @counsellorben showed on his answer) is a good idea. You are going to have a database hit for EVERY request just to see if the request is for an author or a document. Food for thought.

Comment: @Hector Correa  Can you explain how sites like http://jsfiddle.net do it then?

Answer (score 4):

You can achieve what you want with three routes and the appropriate `RouteConstraints`.

First, you need to establish your Routes:

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
{
    routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Author_Document", // Route name
        "{author}/{document}", // URL
        new { controller = "ShowDocument", action = "AuthorDocument" }, // Parameters
        new { author = new MustBeValidAuthor(), document = new MustBeValidDocument() }

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Author", // Route name
        "{author}", // URL
        new { controller = "ShowDocument", action = "Author" }, // Parameters
        new { author = new MustBeValidAuthor() }

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Document", // Route name
        "{document}", // URL
        new { controller = "ShowDocument", action = "Document" }, // Parameters
        new { document = new MustBeValidDocument() }

    routes.MapRoute(
        "Default", // Route name
        "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
        new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
    );
}
```

Next, you need to create your RouteConstraints, which must verify that the information provided is valid:

```
using System; 
using System.Web; 
using System.Web.Routing;  

namespace ExampleApp.Extensions 
{ 
    public class MustBeValidAuthor : IRouteConstraint  
    { 
        public MustBeValidAuthor() { }

        private DbContext _db = new DbContext();

        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)    
        {      
            return (_db.Authors.Where(u => u.AuthorName == values[parameterName].ToString()).Count() > 0);
        }  
    } 

    public class MustBeValidDocument : IRouteConstraint  
    { 
        public MustBeValidDocument() { }

        private DbContext _db = new DbContext();

        public bool Match(HttpContextBase httpContext, Route route, string parameterName, RouteValueDictionary values, RouteDirection routeDirection)    
        {      
            return (_db.Documents.Where(u => u.DocumentName == values[parameterName].ToString()).Count() > 0);
        }  
    } 
}
```

The RouteConstraints will enfoce the validity of the request, and placing the Routes in this order fulfills your requirements.

Comment: Thanks researching RouteConstraints to be able to do this.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that it is possible to do this just by configuring routes.

The problem is how does the program know if the number that you send is an authorid or a documentid.

What you can do is that /1 goes to a page, on that page you do a check to see if it is a document or an author, then you do a Response.Redirect to the actual page, say /author/1.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you want

```
/1  
/2  
/1/2
```

I don't think you can achive that beacuse the first two urls will call the same routing rule. 
You can't know when to call a method instead of another. 
The only solution I can think of, is that if you can discern the ids (for example id from 1 to 10 are authorid while the others are documentId) you can write your custom rulehandler and act accordinlgy calling the right method.

Otherwise you have to put something in the url to make it unique:
"/a1" for authorid and "/d2" for DoumentId would have something like that

```
routes.MapRoute("", "a{authorId}", new { controller = "Home", action = "AuthorDetail" }, new { authorId = @"\d+" });
routes.MapRoute("", "d{documentId}", new { controller = "Home", action = "DocumentDetail" }, new { documentId = @"\d+" });
```

**EDIT**: after your clarification the answer from counsellorben should do what you want

Comment: Thought about pre-pending letters to the first of document but since both author ids and document ids are user generated this would run into errors.

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this where IsAuthorConstraint has a look up to determine if document or author. Alternatively you can route to a bridging Action and put the logic there, before passing on to document or author action.

```
 context.MapRoute(
     "authorid",
     "{authorid}",
     new { action = "Author", controller = "Controller", 
                authorid = -1 },
     new { authorid = new IsAuthorConstraint() }
 );

 context.MapRoute(
     "document",
     "{documentid}",
     new { action = "Document", controller = "Controller", 
                documentid = -1 }
 );

 // assume overload on author action
 context.MapRoute(
     "document and author",
     "{authorid}/{documentid}",
     new { action = "Author", controller = "Controller", 
                documentid = -1, authorid = -1 }
 );
```

I'm not at a computer so may not be exactly right, but hope you get the idea.

Answer (score 0):

You can only achieve this with Route constraints as @counsellorben suggested but there should be no same id for authorid and documentid.

If there is, a conflict is going to occur there.